# Concurrency ForkJoinPool Fibonnacci

Tags: java, concurrency, forkjoinpool

After executing a very good example for ForkJoinPool which is related to searching a directory and its subdirectories for files with a specific extension a conundrum came to my mind.
This program was forking into multiple tasks whenever it found a subdirectory with the directory in other words every subdirectory search
became a separate task and due to parallel processing within a dual core
processor environment the processing was faster than normal.
The example can be found at
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/05/27/forkjoin-framework-tutorial-forkjoinpool-example/

My question is can this kind of processing be carried out for sequential processing tasks like fibonacci series where every consequent no. in the
series is a result of computation of the previous two.
Can this kind of computation be forked into multiple tasks somehow and
therefore compute the result quicker?

Comment: There is a formula for calculating an arbitrarily large Fibonacci number.  This will be much faster than using multiple threads for large numbers, but the formula itself could be partially executed in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..so you are saying that parts of the formula can be provided to different tasks in a forkpool and then combine the results. Could you provide the formula?...Thanks again.

Comment: Here is a discussion of it http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html